# Android Chrome: Audio object takes a long time to begin streaming mp3

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, html5-audio

Chrome on Android sometimes takes a long time to start playing an mp3, even though it should be streamed.

I create an Audio object as follows:

```
player = new Audio();
```

and then in response to a user gesture I do the following:

```
player.src = songName;
player.play();
```

What I've found is that on the OS X version of Chrome, playback starts within 1 second, but on Android, it takes around 10 seconds, depending on the mp3 file I use.

I've created some test code here:
http://buildoneforme.com/so-2016-03-10/

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy View to test on (running Chrome 48), and when I choose the option "Slow load mp3" and hit play, it takes more than 10 seconds before playback starts!

Why does Chrome take so long to start streaming this file?

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by using the Unified Media Pipeline in Chrome on Android.

My version of Chrome has updated to 49.0.2623.91

To set this flag, go to chrome://flags, enable the unified media pipeline flag, and relaunch.